# Error when inserting row to table with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

What is wrong below?

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
import datetime

db = mysql.connect("localhost","root","passworld","employees" )
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO employee(id, firstname, surname, sex, employmentdate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, '%s')" %(id, firstname, surname, sex, employmentdate)

dater = datetime.datetime(2005,1,1)
cursor.execute(["012345","Mark", "Rooney", "M", dater])

OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Mark' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: What do you have id, firstname, surname, sex, employmentdate set to?  Can you use the exact same insert string directly with mysql from a query browser or the mysql command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your sql statement and params to `cursor.execute()`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO employee(id, firstname, surname, sex, employmentdate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, '%s')"
cursor.execute(sql, ["012345","Mark", "Rooney", "M", dater])
db.commit()
```